# Python enterInteger Function - check for valid integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an assignment for school (well, it's extra credit to be exact) where I need to use a function to check if a value that was entered is an integer.
This is the function my teacher would like us to use to start with:

```
def enterInteger():
enteredValue = input(‘Please enter an Integer:’
return int(enteredValue)
```

- no arguments
- will return a valid integer
- will loop until a valid integer is entered
- provides good error messages to the  user as to why the entry was wrong
- it can not crash regardless of what is entered
- if it enters an infinite loop, it is not working!

I've tried messing with a bunch of different code but to no avail. This is the code I've had the most luck with (it's super sloppy, I know. I've been coding Python for about 3 weeks so far with not much teaching):

```
def enterInteger():
    check = 0
    enteredValue = input('Please enter an Integer: ')

    while check == 0:
        if "." in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value has a decimal! Not an integer!")
            return

        elif "\\" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")
            return

        elif "/" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")
            return
        else:
            return int(enteredValue)
            enteredValue = 0
            check = 1

check = enterInteger()

if type(check) is int:
    print("The entered value is an integer!")
else:
    enterInteger()
```

When I run this and enter a real integer, it works fine, but if I enter a non-integer, it doesn't enter the loop correctly. It also doesn't work if I enter a non-integer followed by an integer.

Any help I can get will be much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to look into `try`; could make this both simpler and more effective.

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop? You return in every single one of your branches, so it only ever iterates once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` causes the function to immediately terminate. You return in every branch of your if-elif-else block, so your loop can never execute more than once.

The most straightforward solution is to remove every `return` except `return int(enteredValue)`. You'll also need to move the `input` call inside the loop since you want them to re-enter the value after a failure.

```
def enterInteger():
    check = 0

    while check == 0:
        enteredValue = input('Please enter an Integer: ')
        if "." in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value has a decimal! Not an integer!")
        elif "\\" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")

        elif "/" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")
        else:
            return int(enteredValue)
            enteredValue = 0
            check = 1

check = enterInteger()

if type(check) is int:
    print("The entered value is an integer!")
else:
    enterInteger()
```

A couple more improvements: there's not much point having code after a `return`, since it will never get executed, so you may as well delete `enteredValue = 0` and  `check = 1`. And since `check` will always be zero now, you may as well make the loop unconditional. And `enterInteger` always returns an int, so there's no point in checking that `check` is an integer.

```
def enterInteger():
    while True:
        enteredValue = input('Please enter an Integer: ')
        if "." in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value has a decimal! Not an integer!")
        elif "\\" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")
        elif "/" in enteredValue:
            print("The entered value is a fraction! Not an integer!")
        else:
            return int(enteredValue)

check = enterInteger()
```

This still doesn't satisfy the "it can not crash regardless of what is entered" requirement, though -- for instance, if the user enters "Hello", or hits ctrl-C. You may need to look into exception handling to cover those situations.

Comment: Yea, I've got some scripts to handle letters or characters, so that won't be a problem. I appreciate the help man. I always seem to make my Python scripts way too over-complicated.